# Price not showing, and Sales tag now showing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price

I currently have a wordpress website where users can upload and sell their music. in the post page for woocommerce, i had a custom 'regular price' field that would give the user a dropdown with prices too select. it has been working all along until recently, now the price no longer shows on the front end and a sales tag now appears on the product images.

here is the code for the custom price field:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'theme_slug_custom_product_field' );

function theme_slug_custom_product_field() {
  woocommerce_wp_select(array( 
    'id' => '_regular_price'
    , 'label' => __( 'Regular Price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')'
    , 'data_type' => 'price'
    , 'options' => array(
      ''=>Free
      , '0.99'=>Singles
      , '4.99'=>Mixtapes
      , '9.99'=>Albums ) 
  )
);
}
```

I really need to figure out what is causing this.

Comment: you need to check for front end where your pricing field is fetching.

Comment: Please give Site URL.,so we can check it.

Comment: www.afrohiphop.com ive put a test product there for you to see the problem, the add to cart is there, price field gone, and now there is a sale sticker present. I also have a plugin that creates a "download now" button when price is set to "free". But the problem only arises when i use the other price options.

Comment: In Woocomerce has functionality if you do not enter price then it will not display on front site.
You can add 0 price in price filed ,so it can see free .

Comment: Yes, but when you select the other options in the dropdown as you can see in the array, it adds puts in that price. This has been working all along until today, i havent installed any new plugins, the problem just started now

Comment: You can use general product on drop down option and add price as Rs. 0,then it display you price.

Comment: thanks for all the help, i found the cause of the problem.

Comment: thanks,please up vote on my comment.